# Error in code calculating aitchison distance

Tags: r

I want  to calculate the aitchison distance between all pair of rows of a matrix using `Adist` function. I am testing with iris data, I did that with a `for` script however when I run the code I have this message:

> Error in adist[i] <- aDist(X[i - 1, ], X[i, ]) : object of type
>   'closure' is not subsettable

I appreciate any help.
Anybody could help me, thanks in advance
Here is the code:

```
X <- iris [ ,1:3]
for(i in 1: nrow (X)) {
    adist[i] <- aDist( X[i-1, ], X[i, ])
}
```

Comment: `adist` is an R function name from package utils (`?adist`). Your error is caused by "adist[i] <-" which tries to assign a value to a subset of a function. This operation is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks Otto Kassi, i removed the subset trouble but now i obtain a unique value of Adist, when i actually interested in all pair rows Adist values, do you have any sugestion? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for loop:

```
library('robCompositions') 
X <- iris [ ,1:3]

a <- vector('numeric', length=nrow(X) )
for(i in 1: nrow (X)) {
  a[i] <- aDist( X[i-1, ], X[i, ])
}
```

A more R like approach would be

```
library('robCompositions') 
X <- iris [ ,1:3]

aDistFun <- function(x, r){
  return(aDist( x[r-1, ], x[r, ])) 
}

a <- sapply(seq(1, nrow(X)), FUN=aDistFun, x=X )
```

Comment: Otto kassi thank you very much, it has been really helpfull. Regards